# Redlock.net can't aquire lock

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redlock.net

Using:

```
StackExchange.Redis v1.1.608.0
RedLock.net v1.7.4.0
```

This code always returns **false** after 250-600ms:

```
var eps = new [] { new DnsEndPoint("localhost", 6379) };
var lf = new RedisLockFactory(eps);
var resource = "the-thing-we-are-locking-on";
var expiry = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
using (var redisLock = lf.Create(resource, expiry))
{
    Response.Write("Lock acquired: " + redisLock.IsAcquired);
}
```

I'm struggling to work out why, as I'm able to cache things in Redis just fine with `StackExchange.Redis` connection string `localhost,allowAdmin=true`.

In the `Redis` console I can see a client is being connected, but that's as far as it gets.

I've added a firewall rule for port 6379 but nothing changed.

Any ideas on my the lock can never be acquired?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and downgrading Redis' server is not an option for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the issue.  I'm using MSOpenTech Redis server v3.2.100:
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

Rolling back to v3.0.500 appears to fix the issue.  Not ideal, but in testing environment should be OK for now.